# Why am I getting "Type could not be found" and "does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 questions:  the first is why am I getting "The type or namespace could not be found" - referring to PostM in the line

> public PostM myPost = new PostM();

.  The second question is why, in the next line, am I getting "The name BlogID does not exist in the current context"

> myPost.displayPosts(BlogID);

```
namespace Assessment_2
{
    public partial class Addpost2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        **public PostM myPost = new PostM()**; 
        string BlogID;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBlogDate.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
            txtBlogTitle.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            BlogID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        }

        protected void btnSavePost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            string currentUserId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            string comment = txtComments.Text;
            string BlogID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            myPost.addPost(currentUserId, comment, BlogID, Label2);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **myPost.displayPosts(BlogID);**
        }
    }
}
```

PostM.cs contains:

```
namespace Assessment_2
{
    public class PostM
    {
        private string title;
        private string description;
        private DateTime date;
        private SqlDataSource datasource;

    // Class Constructor - creates the object instance.  Invoked by "PostM myblog = new PostM()" - see .cs file

    public PostM()
    {
        this.title = "";
        this.description = "";
        this.date = new DateTime();
        datasource = new SqlDataSource();
    }

    // Procedural methods

    ..........etc
```

Thanks.  Here is the displayPosts method:

```
public string displayPosts(string BlogID)
        {
            this.datasource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Post WHERE ";
            var result = this.datasource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            DataView reader = (DataView)result; // Cast result to DataView

            string posts = "";
            foreach (DataRow row in reader.Table.Rows)   // While DataView contains rows of data
            {
                posts += row["Post_id"].ToString()+",";
                posts += row["Member_id"].ToString() + ",";
                posts += row["Post_Comments"].ToString() + ",";
                posts += row["Post_Date"].ToString() + ",";
                posts += row["Post_Time"].ToString() + ",";
            }
            return posts;
        }

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Addpost2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assessment_2.Addpost2" %>
```

I have resolved it by rebuilding the Project...thanks for your help.

Comment: Issue aside, you seem to miss an end curly bracket in the `PostM` class. Also, can you show your `displayPosts` method in the `PostM` class?

Comment: `"The type or namespace could not be found"`. It could be that your `PostM` resides in another assembly built with a different version of .NET Framework

Comment: Khan To - It was all created in the same version.

Comment: Side issue to your question, but remember that ASP.Net creates a _new instance of your class_ for every post back, which means every event that fires runs in it's own instance. Your `Button1_Click()` code will never run as part of the same class instance as your `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged()` code, and therefore will not see the same `BlogID` variable!

Comment: To address your question, though: what using directives are the top of the file with the `Addpost2` class, and in what folder is the PostM.cs class? You may want to move the PostM.cs class to the special `App_Code` folder.

Comment: One more thing: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Post WHERE ` is not a valid SQL statement, you may want to use a `\n` instead of a comma after the last field in your `posts` string (where you should also be using a StringBuilder!), and you'll want to enclose a number of those fields in quotes or escape any commas in the field data itself.

Comment: Addost2 class is in the Project folder, Joel. I don't have an App_Code file unless I create one myself.  the Page Directive is:

Comment: oops how can I enter a Newline in this editor.  I'll add the Directive via Editing my question.  Sorry to mislead you over the SQL Where - I hadn't finished it.